# how to make those two divs in one line

Tags: html, css

doc.html

```css
.column {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 75%;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
}
.nav {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  height: 200px;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="css2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container elem">
    <div class="nav"></div>
    <div class="elem column"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I wrote doc.html and css2.css according to this guide [learnlayout](http://learnlayout.com/inline-block-layout.html). but the page looks like this.
how to make those two parts in one line?
[image: doc.html]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the typical whitespace problem with `inline-block`. You can always solve it by assigning `font-size: 0;` to the parent element.

```css
.container.elem {
  font-size: 0;
}
/* remember to reset font-size to what you need in child elements */

.column {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 75%;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
}
.nav {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  height: 200px;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container elem">
  <div class="nav"></div>
  <div class="elem column"></div>
</div>
```

Another solution would be to make both divs float left, but that has it's own problems and complexity which is why I'd advise sticking with inline-blocks.

Answer (score 6):

Your CSS is correct; this issue is a well known whitespace problem. You need to make sure that there is no whitespace between the tags:

```
<body>
    <div class="container elem"
        ><div class="nav"></div
        ><div class="elem column"></div
    ></div>
</body>
```

This is because your content is inline, which makes the whitespace between `.nav` and `.elem` flow. It's small (around 4px), but enough to separate your `<div>`s and break your layout.

By placing the closing bracket right next to the starting bracket in the next element, all the whitespace in between is instead inside the tag, not part of the content (and since tags can contain whitespace between attributes and tag names, this is OK).

Comment: Then why dont you promote his answer. please give an up vote him

Comment: This fixes the cause, but in many situations this is not an option, for example if the HTML is being generated by some other code that you don't control. So it's important to know how to fix it in all cases (see my answer). Good explanation of the problem, though, that's why I will upvote.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with whitespace. To fix it, apply this CSS to the container:

`.container{
  font-size:0;
}`

Answer (score 0):

It's simply make them into one line, except if the parent width is setted and their combined width is bigger than their parents.

```
.container.elem div{
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: This works, but the parent element's height will totally collapse unless you apply a clearfix afterwards.

Comment: Oh, I forget the height.